# codeigniter sqlite not giving results

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter

i just started working with codeigniter and with sqlite,

i have succesfully loaded the sqlite file but when i try to run a get request i get this:

```
Table 'gl0rix.gl0rix' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM `gl0rix`
```

the full code:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database("https://****/*/****/database.sqlite");
}

public function getAll() {
    $query = $this->db->get("gl0rix");
    if ($query->num_rows() >= 1) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

so can anybody please help me?
i'm using codeIgniter 3.0.0

Comment: Is there really a 0 (zero) in the table name? Or is it a typo?

Comment: there is a 0 instead of a o

Comment: Your database name `gl0rix` and table name `gl0rix`? The code you provided is hard to find error.